# Set base URL dynamically in angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on an AngularJS project. I removed # from the URL using  and $locationProvider.html5mode().

Depending upon environment, I want the href attribute for base tag to be dynamically updated from a config file. I created an env.js that contains simple configurations.

**env.js**

```
(function (window) {
  window.__env = window.__env || {};

  window.__env.baseUrl = '/';

  window.__env.enableDebug = true;
}(this));
```

I used this env file in my app.js and inside app.run() updated $rootScope.baseurl to baseUrl in env.js. It is working fine inside console.log() but not in my index.html. I am getting the uncompiled code i.e `{{ $rootScope.baseurl }}`

**app.js**

```
import controllers from './controllers';

        var env = {};

        if (window) {
            Object.assign(env, window.__env);
        }

        var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.router', controllers]);

        app.constant('__env', env);

        app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

            $stateProvider.state("home", {
                url: "/",
                templateUrl: "app/components/home/home.view.html",
                controller: "HomeController"
            }).state("login", {
                url: "/login",
                templateUrl: "app/components/login/login.view.html",
                controller: "LoginController"
            });

            $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                enabled: true,
                requireBase: true
            });
        });

       app.run(function($rootScope, __env){
          $rootScope.baseurl = __env.baseUrl;
          console.log($rootScope.baseurl);
      });
```

**Index.html**

```
    <html ng-app="myapp">
        <head>
            <title>MYAPP</title>
            <base href="{{ baseurl }}">
        </head>

        <body>
            <div ui-view>
            </div>
        </body>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="public/lib/js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="public/lib/js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="env.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="public/app.js"></script>

    </html>
```

Please help me out . Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can't use angular to set it since it needs to be set before any requests are made for page resources like scripts, stylesheets, images etc since you are using relative paths

You could try replacing the `<base>` with something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="env.js"></script>
<script>
      document.write('<base href="' + window.__env.baseUrl + '" />');
</script>
```

Or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="env.js"></script>
<base id="base">
<script>        
   document.getElementById('base').href = window.__env.baseUrl;
</script>
```